# ngBootstrap - ngb-carousel inside modal is invisible

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

using ngb-carousel to show images inside "modal-body" tag of the ngbModal.
No errors, and images are there when i inspect the img element, but the carousel itself is "invisible".

**PS !**
Have tried to adjust height and width on each element (div's, img's) in the carousel tree, without success.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h2>Bildegalleri</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body m-4">
    <ngb-carousel #carousel>
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let media of galleryMedia">
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img [src]="imageService.getQualityPreview(media.previewLargeBlobId)" class="d-block w-100 h-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" (click)="close(false)" (keyup)="close(false)">
        Lukk
    </button>
</div>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Have googled around but haven't found any solution to this.